# How to send notification email to individual users

Tags: rules, entities, notifications

I want to send notification email to some users when a node is created in my site. The author should select the individual users in the node creation form and then after save the node email will be sent to those users.
I use **Entity Reference** and **Rules** modules to do that but I don't know how set the right action.

Comment: I am using Drupal 7 and there is no 'CCK heading' and no 'Load a referenced node' in the rules action dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just implemented the same thing this morning. I hope my solution will help you, but it probably depends on if your content type field is set up like mine.

My user list is presented via an Entity Reference view that I created. Users check off who they want email sent to and save the content type.

My rule is as follows:

```
Event: 
    After saving new content

Conditions: 
    Content is of type 
        Parameter: Content: [node], Content types: User message

Actions:
    Add a variable
        Parameter: Type: List of user items, Value: [node:field-people]
        Provides variables: List of members to email (members_to_email)

    Loop
        Parameter: List: [members-to-email]
        List item: Current member (member)

        Send mail
            (contents of email listed here)
```

You'll obviously have different names for your content type, node field, variable names, etc. but hopefully this will get you started in the right direction. If you want the export of the Rule instead of what I posted here, let me know. I thought that showing you what I did through the interface might be an easier start for you.

Comment: I forgot to say, that I know the original question was marked as a duplicate, but the provided question/answer was not the correct solution for my setup in Drupal 7. So, the answer linked to may be for Drupal 6? If that's the case, the question isn't a duplicate but could probably be edited to say it's for Drupal 7.

The referenced answer also doesn't send to a list of selected users.

Comment: Thanks because of your answer. I can not exactly say that this solution is true because i can not test it on my localhost but theoretically seems it is a the right solution. About the referenced answer for the duplicate question I should say that question and its answer is not satisfy my need and that is not what I want. Your answer is the thing I want. Thanks again.

Comment: I test it in another way than sending email to selected users and it works correctly. Really thank you @Cookie Monster.